# Bootstrap 3 - space around panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a form inside a Panel in bootstrap

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<form>
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Search</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label1</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label2</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label3</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label4</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I run it, the panel spans from the far left to the far right. How can I get some spacing on the left and right so that panel boundary can be easily distinguished from the browser boundary.

[image: Spacing Left and Right]

Comment: Have you used the `container` class to surround your html?

Comment: You can add `container-fluid` class on `form`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap your panel within a container-fluid class

**example snippet**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
<form>
<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Search</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label1</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label2</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label3</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label4</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

With custom css--

```css
.wrapper {
margin-left: 2%;
margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
<form>
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Search</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label1</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label2</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label3</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label4</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! It does the trick. However, it gives me little more spacing than I need. Is there a way to control the spacing the container class provides?

Comment: you need to use custom styling in that case. Add `margin-right and margin-left`. wait updating my answer with that.. also updated my snippet with class=container fluid take a look

Comment: Ok updated my answer..choose whatever option that works for you..hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just add some margin to the `.panel`

```css
.panel { margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<form>
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Search</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label1</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label2</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label3</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <label>Label4</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```